# WordPress - Optimize the Meta Query for 3 meta keys at a time

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, optimization

##### Records in `post_meta` as follow:

| post_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | price | 10 |
| 1 | price_to | 5000 |
| 2 | price_type | 'POA' |
| 3 | price | 12000 |
| 3 | price_to | 17000 |
| 4 | price | 1200 |
| 4 | price_to | 8000 |
| 5 | price_type | 'POA' |

##### Code Snippet

```
<?php
$price_from = '20';
$price_to = '700';

$meta_query_price[] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'    =>  $price_from,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price_to',
            'value'    =>  $price_to,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'  => '>='
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'price_type',
        'value'    =>  'POA',
        'type'    =>  'value',
        'compare'  => 'LIKE'
    ),
);
```

##### Output

| post_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | price | 10 |
| 1 | price_to | 5000 |
| 2 | price_type | 'POA' |
| 5 | price_type | 'POA' |

Above code is executed perfectly issue is when I add `price_type` to the meta_query to extend data it will cause the speed issue.
The result come perfect but time will be very high.

> So, is there any tricks to do this kind of query in WordPress?

Comment: the post meta table wasn't designed for fast searching/filtering, if you need to filter/group posts by a value, that's what taxonomies are for. Have you considered using a custom taxonomy named `price_type` instead? If you already know what types of price there will be then this will provide an enormous scaling performance boost over post meta

Comment: also keep in mind this isn't a discussion thread, so you need to phrase your question in a way that you can mark an answer as the correct answer, you can't just ask for tips

Comment: @TomJNowell you are absolutely perfect. I have modified some code and it's worked perfect. Please review once why it's happening still not understood to me.

Comment: I see you wrote an answer/solution below, but it's worded as if the code in your question is broken, but your question says it works fine and asks not how to fix it, but how to optimise/speed it up. Can you fix your question or the answer to make it clear which one so it's not confusing for other people?

Answer (score 0):

### Conclusion - In my case I tried below

When I changed placement of last meta or at the first place worked perfectly.

```
<?php
$price_from = '20';
$price_to = '700';

$meta_query_price[] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'price_type',
        'value'    =>  'POA',
        'type'    =>  'value',
        'compare'  => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'    =>  $price_from,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price_to',
            'value'    =>  $price_to,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'  => '>='
        ),
    ),
);
```